# Need Help in calculating sum of related filed in contact object and display in account

Tags: trigger

I am getting null pointer exception when I execute below code.

```
trigger suminaccount on Contact (after insert,after update) {

    List<id> acc_id = new List<id>();
    map<id,account> mapid = new map<id,account>();
    if(trigger.isinsert ||trigger.isupdate){  
    for (contact con :trigger.new){
        if(con.accountid != null){

            acc_id.add(con.accountid);
        }
    } 
}


if(trigger.isdelete){  
    for (contact con :trigger.old){
        if(con.accountid != null){
            acc_id.add(con.accountid);

        }     
    }
}
for(account acc:[select id,contact_sum__c from account where id = :acc_id]) {
    decimal sum = 0;
    for (contact con2: [select id ,Contact_amount__c from contact where accountid = :acc_id]){

        sum = sum + con2.Contact_amount__c;    

    }
    acc.contact_sum__c = sum;
    mapid.put(acc.id,acc);
}   

if( mapid.values().size() > 0){
    update mapid.values();  
}

}
```

Comment: Whenever you're getting an error, it's always helpful to include the text of the error message _verbatim_. The error should tell you the line that it's occurring on, and that'd make it easier for people to track down the issue.

Comment: Proper indentation, and providing code that will compile is also important. I've downvoted you for not doing this from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing to check for `null` values in `Contact.Contact_amount__c`.

When you evaluate Integers (among other things, including Booleans) in Apex, the value must be non-`null`, or you receive a `NullPointerException`. This is confusing because we're conditioned to look for accessing a property (such as `someObject.someField`) to get a `NullPointerException`, but this is one place where that's not enough.

While you could fix the immediate problem by changing your query to exclude nulls, there are other problems with this approach. You have SOQL in a loop where you should be using a [bulkified](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) [SOQL aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) to get the `SUM(Contact_amount__c)`. (See the links for more). Your trigger will exhaust SOQL limits quickly in bulk update or insert use cases; even if this is the only code running in the transaction, which might not be the case, you'll receive a limits exception as soon as the total of affected Accounts reaches 100.

Some other issues that need to be fixed:

- Your trigger fails to take into account reparented Contacts: the value on the old parent Account will be wrong.
- While you have code to handle deletions, your trigger is not running on the delete event.
- You are not handling undeletes at all.
- You really need to use a trigger framework/handler class pattern here. Your trigger will rapidly grow unmaintainable and difficult to reason about with all of the logic in the trigger body.
- You are reinventing the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) wheel.